# Really slow fetch in Meteor

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query

I'm pulling data from a collection in Meteor/MongoDB.  There are about 15,000 total documents, and the query is pulling roughly half of them (8,100).  The fetch (before doing anything with it) is taking 5-7 seconds, as reported by Kadira.

There are indexes on the relevant fields, and I can run the find() in 20-50ms - so it's the fetching that's the problem, not the finding.  And this time excludes actually doing anything with the documents - it's just the find().

Each document is about a dozen fields, mostly short (<30 character) strings with a couple ISODates and a couple arrays of 1-2 strings.  All in all, the total dataset (all 8000 records) is about 5 megabytes.

This is all on the server - nothing's being sent to the client.

Is that duration normal?  If not, what might I consider doing to speed it up?

Comment: If you run the same query, returning the same number of documents, using the mongodb cli do you get the same duration? Could just be a slow connection on one end, and not an issue with the fetch method.

Comment: 1. Reduce the number of fields you're publishing, 2. Reduce the number of documents you're publishing at the same time (do you really need all 8k docs on the client?) 3. If you're doing aggregation on the server of some kind use the mongo aggregation framework and let the db do the work directly, 4. Solid State Disks!

Comment: @michel-floyd: This is all on the server - nothing's being published to the client.  This is part of a routine that's supporting some custom reporting.  The server takes report parameters from the client (which collections, fields, etc.) and then effectively joins the collections together.  The result then goes in a collection which is sent to the client on a piecemeal basis.  That part's working fine.  Sounds like I might need to rearchitect the whole thing, though - I never would have imagined that pulling 5 megabytes of data into memory on the server would take so long.

Comment: @brian-shamblen: not a connection issue - this is all happening on the server.

Comment: Are you at least using `this.unblock()` to allow the method to run without blocking new requests from the client?

Comment: No - good point.  But again, it doesn't seem like it should be taking anywhere near this long.  Are my expectations of mongo just too high?  There's not even any computation being done here - I'm just loading from the database into an array.

Comment: Another data point.  In RoboMongo, if I run the query and do a toArray(), it takes less than a second.  It seems like that should take just as much time as meteor's fetch().  Just seems like something odd's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... not sure exactly what was causing it, but a change from one database hosting provider to another fixed it.

Comment: Care to share the before and after database hosting providers?

Comment: modulus.io --> compose.io

Comment: haha I'm on compose.io and experiencing the same problem, did you ever diagnose it? I cant switch providers

Comment: I never did diagnose it. I assumed it was an issue with the modulus configuration. Sorry...